# Reduce number of js request in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

I already merged js files and set production mode, but all js files still loading in the head section along with merged js file.

Comment: can u please enable JavaScript bundling. check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html

Answer (score 0):

Merging of JS file in Magento combine only js in the head, but do not files that loaded asynchronously.

To merge all files you need to enable bundling. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html for details. Please pay attention that better to disable merging if bundling is enabled.

Also, bundling has drawbacks, so please read about advanced bundling mechanism https://github.com/magento/baler/blob/master/docs/WHY_CUSTOM.md